# How to convert an input type of 'time' into a string while using ng-change in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-change

I'd like to convert a time input into a string or a timestamp, so that it will be supported by Firebase.

For example, the following code will not work, because the input has a type of time.

HTML

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
      <input ng-change="data.$save()"  ng-model="data.text">
       {{data.text}}
      <br>
        <input type='time' ng-change="data.$save()"  ng-model="data.time"></input>
      {{data.time}}
</body>
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","$firebase", function($scope,$firebase)                                      
    {
      var ref = new Firebase('https://welcome.firebaseIO.com/Data/RandomUser');
        $scope.data = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
    }]);
```

See [codpen here](http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/RWxrKO?editors=101).

I've tried to convert the input of time with the following with no luck:

Tried adding .toString() at the end of the data.time

```
<input type='time' ng-change="data.$save()"  ng-model="data.time.toString()">
```

Tried adding .toString() at the end of the data.$save()

```
<input type='time' ng-change="data.$save().toString()"  ng-model="data.time">
```

I've also looked at the ng-change [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) which suggests that the expression is evaluated immediately, so perhaps this is not possible with ng-change.

Comment: Have you looked into [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting to not use ng-change to something like ng-keydown

Comment: The model value for a `time` input will be a Date object, so you can't save it directly to Firebase. Also, you should probably be using the latest versions of Firebase/Angularfire.

Comment: You're using an alpha release of AngularFire. Upgrade to a stable 1.x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date manipulation is given as [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/syuzw9k1/) in the AngularFire API docs (search for "To illustrate, let’s create a factory that creates Widget instances, and transforms dates:") and, as a topic, manipulating data is covered in the section on [extending services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html). There is also [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/syuzw9k1/) demonstrating date manipulations.

Here is the example from the fiddle:

```
/**
 * Add a factory object which parses dates
 */
app.factory('DateFactory', function ($firebaseObject) {
    return $firebaseObject.$extend({
        /**
         * Called each time there is an update from the server
         * to update our data
         */
        $$updated: function (snap) {
            // call the super
            var changed = $firebaseObject.prototype
                .$$updated.apply(this, arguments);
            // manipulate the date
            if( changed ) {
               this.date = new Date(this.date||0);
            }
            // inform the sync manager that it changed
            return changed;
        },

        /**
         * Used when our data is saved back to the server
         * to convert our dates back to JSON
         */
        toJSON: function() {
            return angular.extend({}, this, {
                // revert Date objects to json data
                date: this.date? this.date.getTime() : null
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note that, in general, numeric dates are much more useful than strings (easier to parse, sortable, queryable, etc) and these examples use that superior storage strategy. Converting that to a string should be self-explanatory.